# Flutter: How to prevent scroll and make it with dynamic height? Flutter Html Editor - Enhanced

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have added one widget for the HTML editor in SinglScrollView with other widgets and want to like the Gmail app to compose an email screen with the editor's dynamic height without scrolling the HTML editor.

I have used https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.!